# Can't travel from Siwa to Alexandria

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

So I'm on a PS4, Bayek level 7, with all of Siwa's missions completed. It says that I have to talk to Bayek's friend to go to Alexandria but when I talk to him he says that he is not ready yet packing my stuff for my trip and then on the screen a message in red and white pops up saying: "This feature hasn't been installed yet, let AC origins install...". I don't understand what is hapenning cause I installed everything and when I checked the updates, it says the game version is up to date. So I've tried restarting the PS4, reinstalling the AC Origins app, yet nothing changes. So I am stuck here and can't advance in story by traveling to Alexandria. Does anyone know what I need to do?

Comment: If you still have the issue, check my edit: Ubisoft would like people with the issue like you to contact them and provide extra information.

Answer (score 2):

According to a [Known Issues thread from Ubisoft](https://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1773724-Assassin-s-Creed-Origins-Known-Issues-Oct-27):

> ## Unable to leave Siwa
>
> Description: We are aware of an issue where players are not able to leave Siwa and receive a “The game has not fully installed yet. Please wait for Assassin’s Creed Origins to finish installing and try again.” pop up.
>   Status: Under Investigation - Please get in touch with the Customer Support if you experience this issue and provide them with as much information as you can.

Looks like the only thing you can do is wait for a patch to be released.

Update: Ubisoft has put in a request for users with the issue in hopes of narrowing down the issue further.